# Reinstating YouTube account which was suspended for repeated Copyright violations

Tags: youtube, copyright

My YouTube account has been suspended due to repeated or severe violations of our Terms of Use and claims of copyright infringement.

Now I have worked it out with the company who put the copyright strikes on my video. As a result those copyright strikes were removed. Now I'm in good standing. As a result, I wondering if I could get my youtube account reinstated?

Answer (score 1):

Follow YouTube's guidelines for appealing a strike as mentioned in [this link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/185111?hl=en)

> #### Appeal a strike
>
> - Visit your [Channel Settings](http://www.youtube.com/account_features)
> - Click the arrow next to the Community Guidelines section to show your strikes
> - Click Appeal this decision link as shown below